# Gulp with Nuxt js Webpack

Tags: webpack, gulp, nuxt.js

Having html markup done by html dev based on gulpfile (+twig-js).

I have to integrate it with nuxtjs.
I'm using nuxt first time but already have vue experience (not bad as I think), but I have no exp in merging such different environments.
I've tried to make nuxt to build scss files included but seems there is absent one image declared in url() in some of these scss so webpack fails. dunno how to ignore this one, googled without success.
so, how would be the best practice to integrate these two environments (html markup based on twig-js with gulpfile versus nuxt webpack)?
I came to the idea that the best way is to allow gulpfile build dist files and to use already built by gulp files (css+some sort of js) in nuxt.config?